# Determine whether $S\cdot T$ is open if $S\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is open and $T$ is any subset of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $S\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ be open and $T$ be any subset of $\mathbb{R}$. I'd like to determine whether or not the set
$$S\cdot T=\{s\cdot t:s\in S,t\in T\}$$
is open. So far, I haven't come up with any useful ideas. But a warm-up question came into my mind: what if we consider the operation of addition instead? In fact, if $S$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $T$ is any subset of the same space, then I'm certain that the set
$$S+T=\{s+t:s\in S,t\in T\}$$
is open. To see it, pick arbitrary points $s,t$ in $S,T$ respectively and find $\epsilon>0$ s.t. the open ball $B(s,\epsilon)$ is contained in $S$. Then it's quite straightforward to show that $B(x+y,\epsilon)\subseteq S+T$, which implies each point in $S+T$ is an interior point.

I transplanted the above argument to the case of multiplication, only to end in disaster. Is there any way to make out? Thank you.

Comment: What if $T =\{ 0\}$?

Comment: An alternative approach for the $S+T$ problem is: $S+T=\bigcup_{t\in T}(S+t)$ is a union of open sets.

Comment: @podiki Maybe you are right. Your $T$ will make $S\cdot T$ become a closed set.

Comment: If $0 \notin T$ or if $0 \in S$, then $S$ open $\Rightarrow S \cdot T$ open.  That's because $$S \cdot T = \cup_{t \in T} St$$ (with the obvious definition), and you can show by multiplying by $\frac 1t$ that $s \in S \Rightarrow st$ is contained in an open ball in $St$.  Since $st \in St$ is arbitrary, that means $St$ is open.  Thus, $S \cdot T$ is a union of open sets.

Comment: @QiyuWen This should be an official answer.